# Отдача распоряжения

Tags: стилистика

Как можно выразить иначе словосочетание "отдача распоряжения" , чтобы это не звучало так коряво?

Comment: Без полного предложения однозначно правильного ответа дать невозможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, в первом ответе не точно. В данном контексте можно сказать "вынесение приказа", например, или просто "распоряжение". Так мне кажется.

Comment: Согласна с Вами. Не во всяком контексте существительное можно заменить глаголом.

Comment: Всё бы ничего, но приказ и распоряжение - это разные документы, имеющие свою специфику в управленческой работе

Comment: Я согласилась с тем, что у Вас не совсем точно. Я не стала отвечать, т.к. мне не хватает контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать "сделать распоряжение(я)" или "распорядиться"